# I can't get re.split to work with numbers, but keep them in the string and together,

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I can't get re.split to work with numbers, but keep them in the string and together
Example:

```
s = ['Amount A 7,791.23', 'Amount B 6,318.94']

for i in range(len(s)):
    re.split('(\d)+', s)
```

Output should be:

```
['Amount A', '7,791.23']
['Amount B', '6318.94']
```

The reason its in this format is because I am copying it from a document. I have gotten it to work with other special characters leading the amounts ($) but it only worked because I didn't need to keep the symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your purpose you should use `str.rsplit` to split the strings with a space from the right, with a maximum of 1 split:

```
s = ['Amount A 7,791.23', 'Amount B 6,318.94']
for i in s:
    print(i.rsplit(' ', 1))
```

This outputs:

```
['Amount A', '7,791.23']
['Amount B', '6,318.94']
```

Comment: I would do that but in my case there are more than one spaces where the 'Amount1' is, something like the title of a category

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer with your new requirements then.